# Add component "Select a rendering popup" in grouped format

Tags: experience-editor, presentation

In my local instance experience editor add component showing a popup **"Select a rendering"** like below

[image]

In My higher environment this popup showing differently like, its showing with the **grouped format tabs**.

Tab names respectively my rendering folder names.

[image]

My question is which settings i need to achieve with group format?

I hope changes will be in sitecore related configs.Because same codes, unicorn items will present in my server and local.

Comment: Is your higher environment using SXA?

Comment: please compare \sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\SelectRendering\SelectRendering.xml file of your local one with the higher environment. If it is not SXA then I very much sure this is a customization. I remember a Sitecore module in the early version 6

Comment: Hi My higher environemnt using SXA. My local doesnt have SXA. Can i achieve this with out using SXA in my loca?

Comment: I would still hope to get answer to this aswell